# cropping in image into an cricle

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I want to crop an image which is rectangular , into a circle of specific diameter. I am able to do it through graphics2D, and I get the image saved, but, when I read it through ImagIO, i get the full image again inspite to it being cropped to a circle. the image is a masked circle, and evrything outside is discarded like a mask. I am attaching the image here. inspite of it being clipped, i get the full image rendered, when i read it through imageIO. here is the code.

```
 int w = bufferedImage.getWidth();
  int h = bufferedImage.getHeight();
  BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

  Graphics2D g2 = output.createGraphics();
  Area areaOval = new Area(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, w, w, 0, 360,
      Arc2D.PIE));
      Shape shapeClipSave = g2.getClip();

      g2.setClip(areaOval);
      g2.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
      g2.setClip(shapeClipSave);
  bufferedImage=output;
  try {
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"png", new File("D:/new.png"));
    bufferedImage= ImageIO.read(new File("D:/new.png"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  g2.dispose();
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. this image which I have attached, is resulting image. I tried writing to output also. but it gives the same result. i opened the image in windows photos. and it shows the correct  circular clipped image.

Comment: Some general advice: 1. Always `dispose()` the `Graphics2D` *before* you write, to make sure all operations are flushed to the underlying image. 2. You should probably also crop the output to the size of your oval (use `new BufferedImage(w, w, ...)` in your example), as anything outside it will be transparent. 3.There's no point restoring the original clip here, as you don't do further operations. Finally, your image looks like expected to me. Do you mean the area outside your circle is *not* transparent?

Comment: PS: Also keep in mind that computer (raster) images are *always* rectangular, even if some parts may be transparent. 

Comment: hi @HaraldK. yes. what i get in the output is the full image itself, with the content outside,not transperent, but having the original image's data.

Comment: Can you post your original image (the giraffe)? And the code you use to read *and display* the image in Java, where you see the non-transparent parts? I find it hard to believe that Java would handle the transparency different than what you see in the screenshot you posted (which is exactly how I would expect it to be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take. I rewrote some parts for performance and better fidelity (I couldn't get the edges of the circular area antialiased using clip). Although your code should also work, in general.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));

    // Remove odd borders (imgur issue?)... Remove this if your input doesn't have borders
    image = image.getSubimage(10, 0, image.getWidth() - 20, image.getHeight() - 10);

    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();

    image = createCircular(image, Math.min(w, h));

    if (!ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("new.png"))) {
        System.err.println("Could not write PNG format");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    image = ImageIO.read(new File("new.png"));

    showItAll(image);

}

private static BufferedImage createCircular(BufferedImage image, int size) {
    BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = output.createGraphics();
    try {
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.fillOval(0, 0, size, size);

        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    } 
    finally {
        g2.dispose();
    }
    
    return output;
}

private static void showItAll(BufferedImage image) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
        {
            setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Using your giraffe as input, I got the following output, the orange background is just to make the transparent parts clearly visible:

[image: Circular selection of image]

Alternatively, if you use the TwelveMonkeys library and the Adobe Path Support module, you can replace:

```
image = createCircular(image, Math.min(w, h));
```

with the following:

```
int size = Math.min(w, h);
image = Paths.applyClippingPath(new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 1, 1), 
                                image.getSubimage(0, 0, size, size));
```

Just be aware that the shape coordinates are relative to the size of the image, not in pixels.

Comment: hello. thank you. this helps a lot. BTW  is there a way I can do this through clip paths in twelve monkeys? like can I add my own circular clippath to the image data and then apply it using Paths.applyClippingPath()?

Comment: Absolutely. You can replace the `createCircular` invocation with `Paths.applyClippingPath(new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 1, 1), bufferedImage.getSubimage(0, 0, size, size))` (where `size = Math.min(w, h)`). The output should be exactly the same. Just be aware that the shape is relative to the size of the image, not in pixels!